# Laravel: How to get URLs of uploaded files?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have created an `upload` folder at the same level of `app` and storing uploaded files there. Now I need to access those file via browser so need to have an `http://` based address.

First, am I doing right? What are Laravel 5.1's recommendation? Where should files be stored? If no recommendation then how do I get ULRs?

Comment: Store the files within your `public folder` create `uploads folder` and then you can simply access from there like as `asset("uploads/your_file")`

Comment: @Uchiha Please make this as answer and I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the files within your `public folder` create `uploads folder` and then you can simply access from there using [`asset()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset) function like as

```
asset("uploads/your_file")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request::root()` to get the root URL of your website and then simply use `Request::root()."/uploads/your_file"`

Comment: thing is that beside `/public/` nothing is exposed to the users.

Comment: @Volatil3 so you have to create upload folder inside public directory and upload files there then use `Request::root()."/public/uploads/your_file"`

Comment: Instead of using `Request::root()` simply use `url()."/uploads/path_to_file"`